Geometry Node Pattern Help?
I am trying to make a pattern using Geometry nodes.
I attached a screenshot of the pattern I am trying to create, and my viewport and workspace attempts thus far.
As you will see I need help with making the pattern, as well as merging the mesh together once it's made. The core element of the pattern I've already modeled as seen in the screenshot. Thanks in advance for your help!




Another approach, you would plug in your objects using the Object Info node and use a Checker texture.



(Blender 4.40)

this was enormously helpful, thank you so much for providing this and the project file!!

Just make two grids, one smaller than the other in the right proportion, and you have all the locations:

File

Hints
If you make your base shape having sides = 1 (X and Y), you can automatically set the scale for X and Y as equal to the spacing, and use a "factor" as input scale instead of an absolute scale as I did.

Joke answer

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)

Imgur mirror
Real answer: after booleans, apply the modifier, clean up the geometry (or create new one from scratch, but you now understand the dimensions and topology it needs to have), and recreate the geonodes after booleans.

Of course if you don't need the detail of smoothed connections like here: https://i.imgur.com/EuQ6o5N.gif then you can get with simple overlapping instancing as in other answers.

I was just coming to the conclusion that if it is a 3D printing job, the answer is different.
